# Make NSArray from NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a `NSMutableArray`. I want to make a `NSArray` from that `NSMutableArray` using for loop of `NSMutableArray`  I tried but I cant do this.

Comment: Post the code that is not working for you and let people here help you fix it.

Answer (score 7):

Rather than loop through the array items, you can turn a mutable array into an immutable array with the `copy` method

```
NSArray *newArray = [myMutableArray copy];
```

`copy` is a handy method. If you send it to a mutable member of a mutable/immutable class cluster, it returns an immutable copy. But if you send it to an immutable member, it just returns the same object with another retain.

There is also `mutableCopy` which will return a mutable version of whatever it is sent to.

The behaviour of returning an owned (retained) object is why the memory management guidelines recommend releasing objects created with `new` `alloc` `retain` or **`copy`** (in a non-ARC environment, of course)

If there is a reason you are trying to use a loop, because you want to change the values of the array before creating a new array, then there are a couple of ways of doing this (loops, enumerations, etc) but we'll need to know more details before we can advise you.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to loop. You can create an unmutable array from a mutable array like this

```
NSArray *myUnMutableArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:myMutableArray];
```